# How to removal double quotes, commas, and brackets in the string array with Ruby and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a string array looks like this:

```
array =  ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

I am using `respond_to do |format|` to parse it `.text` file.

My code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.text { render text: array }
end
```

Now what I want to do here is removal all the double quotes, commas, and also the array bracket `[]` and each value will be separate with line breaks in the text file.

So I want my result looks like this when opening the text file:

```
A
B
C
D
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried simply

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.text { render text: array.join("\n") }
end
```

?